How do we integrate Nifi ConsumeJMS with ActiveMQ Artemis
I have been trying to make changes in existing NiFi code and include certificate and few details from local, which is working and we are able to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis 2.33.0.
The issue is that we are unable to observe the durable connectivity although I see in the logs it's going through the durable connection logic still it misses flow file generated during downtime from JMS server.
The session name is different for MessageConsumer before starting and stopping the processor, but the client ID and subscription name stays same. In fact, the processor throws error if we use durable with different client ID and subscription name.
How can we fix this? Is there any article for same?
I tried to print logs and could see durable logic is getting called still it misses flow files during downtime.

It sounds like you're attempting to use a durable subscription on a JMS topic from Apache NiFi code, but the subscriber is still missing messages when it is not connected. Is that correct?

I am using Artemis 2.33.0

It sounds like you're attempting to use a durable subscription on a JMS topic from Apache NiFi code, but the subscriber is still missing messages when it is not connected. Is that correct?       Yes that's correct

By Durable Logic I mean I have added logger where it is creating a durable consumer and I can see it is using the durable cosumer and calling the code block where durable connection logic is present.

Sure,
I am using Artemis 2.33.0
Yes I am trying to setup a durable subscription topic still the client is missing message when disconnected.
I can see it's able to return a durableConsumer
if (durable) {
                    return session.createDurableConsumer((Topic) destination, subscriptionName, messageSelector, JMSConsumer.this.jmsTemplate.isPubSubDomain());
                }

Link to code: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.14.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jms-bundle/nifi-jms-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/jms/processors/JMSConsumer.java

let me know if you need more input

Do you see the queue for the durable subscriber on the address which represents the JMS topic?

I don't have access to the JMS Provider what should I ask to get verified at JMS Server end?

Also does ConsumeJMS Unsubscribe to a topic when we stop it. I think it's just stop the connection also the subscription and client id has to be maintained at JMS Server end right.

You should verify that the same subscription queue which is created when you create your durable subscription still exists after your subscriber disconnects.

I don't know if ConsumeJMS unsubscribes when when you stop it.

I checked it; the JMS messages have a TTL of 15 minutes. Suppose a message is published to the JMS server at 12:00:00 PM. It will reach ConsumeJMS at 12:14:55. Before this message could reach ConsumeJMS, we will be receiving alarms that were raised before 12:00:00, and in those messages, there is also a delay of over 14 minutes.
So, when we stop it for some time, the messages on the server are already expiring, and hence we could not see the messages during downtime.
I think ConsumeJMS is not consuming all the messages in the topic when we start it; it consumes messages at a fixed rate.
